# Ansible: How to call a playbook from another?

Tags: ansible

I have written a simple playbook to print java process ID and other information of that PID

```
[root@server thebigone]# cat check_java_pid.yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Check PID of existing Java process
      shell: "ps -ef | grep [j]ava"
      register: java_status

    - debug: var=java_status.stdout
```

And when I am calling this with `ansible-playbook check_java_pid.yaml`it's working fine.

Now I am trying to call the above playbook from another one but only for a specific host. So I have written the 2nd playbook as below

```
    [root@server thebigone]# cat instance_restart.yaml
    ---
    - hosts: instance_1
      gather_facts: no

      tasks:
        - include: check_java_pid.yaml
```

But while doing `ansible-playbook instance_restart.yaml`, I am getting below errors

```
    ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled 
    module name, or incorrect module path.

    The error appears to have been in 
    '/home/root/ansible/thebigone/check_java_pid.yaml': line 2, column 3, but 
    may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:

     ---
     - hosts: all
       ^ here


      The error appears to have been in 
      '/home/root/ansible/thebigone/check_java_pid.yaml': line 2, column 3, 
      but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

     The offending line appears to be:

      ---
      - hosts: all
        ^ here
```

Its saying syntax error but there isn't one really AFAIK as I have executed Playbook `check_java_pid.yaml` without any issues.

Requesting your help on understanding this issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With `include` [on the task level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-playbooks) Ansible expects a file with tasks only, not a full playbook. Yet you provide a full playbook as an argument.

You could do it (include) [on a play level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html), but it won't let you achieve what you want.

The play with `hosts: all` defined will always run against all targets (unless you limit it in the command call or the inventory).

Moreover, you will have troubles accessing the `java_status` value from the other playbook (if this was your goal).

---

You need to rethink your structure, for example you can for example extract the task(s) and include them from both plays:

`my_tasks.yml`

```
- name: Check PID of existing Java process
  shell: "ps -ef | grep [j]ava"
  register: java_status

  - debug: var=java_status.stdout
```

`check_java_pid.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - include my_tasks.yml
```

`instance_restart.yml`

```
---
- hosts: instance_1
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - include: my_tasks.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for looking again. its making sense now. will update you once I have tried.

Comment: Working and now I understand, Thank you again.

Comment: This is not the answer to OP.

Answer (score 31):

Here you have examples in official documentation.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html

I had same error as yours after applying the aproved answer. I resolved problem by creating master playbook like this:

```
---
- import_playbook: master-okd.yml
- import_playbook: infra-okd.yml
- import_playbook: compute-okd.yml
```

Comment: This is a great workaround, but I would like to override some variables for each of these imports. Is that possible?